# Как изменить размер шрифта item в menu drawer'а?

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть drawer с элементами, как я могу изменить размер шрифта этих элементов, свойства textSize у item не нашел, и еще можно ли как то сделать так, чтобы после выбора item и повторного открытия drawer'a этот последний выбранный элемент отображался "Зажатым", то есть как бы выбраннным, что-то вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> повторного открытия drawer'a этот последний выбранный элемент
> отображался "Зажатым"

Если я правильно понял твой drawermenu из шаблона...,  это атрибут menu group `group android:checkableBehavior` в твоем случае значение для него `single`. Если данное меню из шаблона то это activity_main_drawer.xml - res\menu

> drawer с элементами, как я могу изменить размер шрифта этих элементов,
> свойства textSize у item не нашел

то нужно взять базовый стиль твоего activity на котором располагается drawermenu, res\values\style.xml и дополнить его, вот например

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <!--        Шрифт для для любых неопределенных атрибутов шрифта-->
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_menu</item>

               <!--        Цвет главного меню+выделение пунктов меню-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ap_blue_2</item>
        <!--        Цвет шапки окна главного приложения-->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ap_blue_2</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

я могу дать не точный ответ, так как я новичок тут и в программировании тоже...учусь самостоятельно

Comment: К сожалению Drawer не из шаблона, но спасибо за попытку помочь)

Comment: group android:checkableBehavior - работает независимо от этого. нужно объединить menuitem в group. По поводу стилей, разница моего от вашего в том что вы создали свой стиль и назначили его NavigationView. Мой же это внесение изменения в текущий стиль вашего активити, суть одна. ))) я к тому что это не попытка это один из вариантов, который работает)))

Comment: Ок, ваш вариант тоже кому-то пригодится))

Comment: По сути оба решения практически одинаковы, просто если на них наткнется новичек, он сможет найти способ под свою ситуацию